# How to get values from query string and pass it to new page using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

currently I m using following code in my site in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).php?$ comman.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

This redirects user to comman.php page say, user requests

http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/page1.php

will redirects to

http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/comman.php?cat=page1

This works fine. My question is how can I achieve following

http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/page1.php?var1=123

to redirect

http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/comman.php?cat=page1&param=123

i.e. whatever value passed to url using get method to add in my new url.

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).php?$ comman.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` stands for `Query String Append`. Anything after the `?` in the original URL will be appended to the rewritten URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ass QSA to your rule, i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pageid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `QSA` flag in your `RewriteRule` for that.

See the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).